# Bazel: How to pass relative path of a file as an "args" to java_binary?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules, bazel-java

I have a file `hello.txt` that lives in `src/main/resources` folder.

I am using a `java_binary` rule and need to pass this `hello.txt` file as an argument.

```
java_binary(
    name = "Hello",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/java/**"]),
    args = ["/Users/jdoe/repo1/libraries/myproj/src/main/resources/hello.txt"],
    deps = [...],
)
```

The above works when I provide the full path, however it fails if I try with a relative path like `src/main/resources/hello.txt`.

How do I provide a relative path to the args attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binary depends on the resource file `hello.txt`, but Bazel is not aware of this. Make `hello.txt` a data dependency of your `java_binary`, i. e. add the attribute `data = ["src/main/resources/hello.txt"]`. Bazel runs your executable in a sandbox, i.e. somewhere where your `hello.txt` is not present. The data dependency makes sure that the file is copied to the place where it is needed.

Comment: thanks! i ended up using a filegroup{} and passed that instead under args. but your suggested way works too.